# Loading library functions into a form after form has started

Tags: forms, function, powershell, loading

is it possible to load a library into a form after the form has started?

I tried:

```
$mycheckbox.add_CheckStateChanged({
if ($mycheckbox.checked){
. "D.\MyLibrary.ps1"}
})
```

The functions in MyLibrary.ps1 are not available after the call. Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe provide the full path your ps1. Unless youre already in that directory, then remove the *d* to properly for source it

Comment: @Abraham Zinala, Actually I use as command to call my library file . "$PSScriptRoot\MyLibrary.ps1"

Comment: When I execute it before form.activate and form.show, it works fine, the functions from the library are available and usable but after form.show with a checkbox event, the libraries are not loaded into the form.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the Import Module Cmdlet.

1. In the library file export functions with
   Export-ModuleMember -Function FunctionName
2. Change file name to *.psm1
3. Execute Import-Module "Path\ModuleName.psm1"

Ready!